# Sorting in VS14 doesn't work correctly while in VS10 it does?

Tags: c++, sorting, visual-studio-2015

I'm writing a point-n-click game in C++ and SFML. To this day I was using Visual Express 2010, but today I decided to upgrade to Visual 2015 due to its C++11 features. But I encountered a problem I cannot find resolution to.

As it is a 2D p'n'c game I have a Room which represents whole board player actually visits. Room consists of several Layers which are just background and foreground images. To ensure those layers will be drawn in correct order I added a z-order parameter to them and then I sort them using z-order. So it actually works like this:

```
Room bao;
bao.AddLayer(Layer("bao/gfx/back.png", Vector2f(0, 50), 0));
bao.AddLayer(Layer("bao/gfx/occluder.png", Vector2f(0, 50), 0));
bao.AddLayer(Layer("bao/gfx/front.png", Vector2f(0, 50), 0));
bao.SortLayers();
```

I create a room, add some layers to it (z parameter is the last one, it's zero here in all three layers) and then sort them. Sorting here has no use actually, but it might come in handy later. It's quite simple and in VS10 I haven't had any problems with that. Not even one. But when I moved my project to VS14 (and by saying "moved" I mean I just created a new project in VS14, added 32-bit sfml 2.3.2 libraries compatible with VS14 and copied the code to this new project), compiled it and then run it I saw what is on the left side of this picture:

[image]

Only the first layer ("back.png") was drawn while all three layers I have here should be. It should look like on the right side. I quickly found the problem was with sorting layers. When I comment line:

```
bao.SortLayers();
```

It works allright. Sorting is done by sort() method from algorithm lib:

```
class Room {
   private:
      vector<Layer*> layers;
      //some other fields

   public:
      //constructors, other methods
      void SortLayers() { sort(layers.begin(), layers.end()); }
};
```

Layer is a struct which looks like this:

```
struct Layer {
    Texture tex;
    Sprite spr;
    int zorder;

    //constructors

    bool operator<(const Layer& a) const {
        return zorder < a.zorder;
    }
};
```

I override operator < here... Well, it's really simple code and I really had NO problems with it in VS10. I started this project in July, but left after a few days and came back to it just yesterday. For three months I sometimes run the executable and everything was always working nice. Even yesterday, when I came back to this game and started coding items everything was working perfectly for whole four hours I spent on it. And today I upgraded VS to VS14 and bah! There's a problem...

Comment: `Room::layers` is a `vector` of pointers, sorting it should compare the addresses of your layers (i.e., the pointers) not the pointees. Add some output to your overloaded `operator<` to verify that it is indeed used.
Btw do not use owning raw pointers in STL containers.

Comment: Two things I would call attention to: In your code, you specify 0 as the z parameter for all your layers. It may be possible that there was a change to the sorting algorithm between 2010 and 2015 in how they guarantee behavior of identical items, that you're no longer getting in 2015. Also, like @MatthäusBrandl indicated, make sure your comparing algorithm is handling pointers of your layers, not the layers themselves.

Comment: @Xirema is right actually, even if you compare pointees, they are all equal in the sense of your less than operator. I think there are no guarantees regarding the order of equal elements.

Comment: I forgot to mention that when I was trying to solve this problem I changed z-order parameters to 0, 10 and 20 respectively, but this had no effect at all.

Comment: R Sahu's answer seconds my comment, check  [this code](http://ideone.com/2vncFU) as well. I don't understand why it worked before actually, it shouldn't.

Comment: Yes, I already implemented R Sahu's code to my project. And I also have no clue why my code was working fine for whole three months and crashed when I moved it to VS14...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In,

```
void SortLayers() { sort(layers.begin(), layers.end()); }
```

You are sorting `layers` by pointer values, not the contents of the objects.

You can create a custom functor/function that will do the right thing for sorting the objects by the values of the objects the pointers point to.

```
bool compareLayers(Layer* lhs, Layer* rhs)
{
    return (*lhs < *rhs);
}
```

and use it in the call to sort:

```
void SortLayers() { sort(layers.begin(), layers.end(), compareLayers); }
```